# Importing specific classes from a file located in a python package

Tags: python, package

I have a python package `main` and `other_python_files` which are like:

```
main/
    __init__.py
    lib.py
    other_python_files/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

Let `lib.py` contain a class called `MyClass`. When I do `from main import lib.py` and use `MyClass` inside `test.py` I get the error that `MyClass` is not defined.

I tried doing `from main import MyClass` inside the init file in the `main` directory but I still get the same error. What should I do to achieve importing a specific class from the `lib.py` file ?

Comment: Your package example is inclear.  Why is "other python files" in there twice?  Please fix it and indent things to make clear what is nested inside what.

Comment: The other one was actually showing the contents of other python files. I edited to show this

Comment: I have edited your post to show what I understand you as meaning.  Please correct it if I did it wrong.  It's better to just show the entire directory tree with indentation to indicate nesting, instead of showing each directory separately.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn the way you did is much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to import that class out of `lib`:

```
from main.lib import MyClass
```

Or use `lib.MyClass` in place of `MyClass`.

You can also import `MyClass` inside of the `__init__.py` file that's in `main`, which lets you import it the way you originally tried:

```
__all__ = ['MyClass']

from lib import MyClass
```

You can read about `__all__` here: [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)